# Why would white play Qf5

Tags: puzzles, sacrifice

I was playing the following [puzzle](https://lichess.org/training/D4L1T) on lichess playing the black pieces and found the move `Bf5`, expecting either `Qe2` or `Qe3`, resulting in me taking the white bishop on `c2` and completing the puzzle.

The play by white however surprised me as white instead played `Qxf5`, allowing for me to take the queen with `exf5`

If instead white had played either `Qe2`or `Qe3` I would at most have won a bishop on `bxc2`. and left me with no more ways to threaten the queen (`Qe5` doesn't work due to the D pawn, `Kd4` dito with C pawn), and it doesn't look like white gains a superior position due to the sacrifice

Am I missing some other big opportunity here that would give black a big advantage if white had not sacrificed the queen?

```
 r3k1nr/5pp1/p1nqp2p/1p1p4/3P2b1/2PQ1N2/PPBN1PPP/R3K2R b KQkq - 1 12
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the best move would have just been taking White's bishop on c2, like you assumed.

Why Stockfish has a slight preference for Qxf5 is a little puzzling. If you think about it though, White has to choose between losing a bishop (a loss of ~3 material points in human estimations) versus losing a queen for a bishop and pawn (~5 material points). Then there's the fact that White will be the only one with a nice bishop, as opposed to Black's bishop ruling supreme. Also, Black's pawn chain is broken up a bit.

In any event though, the position is dead lost for White in either case.